# TextEditController clears the text field's text

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an application about to do. But there is an issue. I write some text to the text field. But When I add a new text field it clears the text filed's text. And when I delete the TextEditingController it fixes the issue. But then when I try to slide it right or left it clears the text again.

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}


class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int today=1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Takveam"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "$today",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
                letterSpacing: 1,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Todo()),
              );
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                today-=1;
                if(today<1)
                  today=31;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                today=31;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            today+=1;
            if(today>31)
              {
                today=1;
              }
          });
        },
        child: Text("Dıkla"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Todo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoState createState() => _TodoState();
}

class _TodoState extends State<Todo> {

  int i=1;
  List<Column> todoos = [
    Column(),

  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To do"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: i,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Slidable(
                actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          controller: new TextEditingController(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            print(i);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconSlideAction(
                    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[200],
                    icon: Icons.check_circle,
                  )
                ],
                secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                  IconSlideAction(
                      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[200],
                      icon: Icons.more_horiz
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            i+=1;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the code in your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Each item need a `TextEditingController` 
For demo purpose, I remove background color

Step 1: declare a `List<TextEditingController> listTexttCtrl = [TextEditingController()];` 
Step 2: In `FloatingActionButton`, add `listTexttCtrl.add(TextEditingController());`

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            i += 1;
            listTexttCtrl.add(TextEditingController());
          });
        },
```

Step 3: `TextField` `controller` attribute use `listTexttCtrl[index]`

```
TextField(
            controller: listTexttCtrl[index],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int today = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Takveam"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "$today",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
                letterSpacing: 1,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Todo()),
              );
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                today -= 1;
                if (today < 1) today = 31;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                today = 31;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            today += 1;
            if (today > 31) {
              today = 1;
            }
          });
        },
        child: Text("Dıkla"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Todo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoState createState() => _TodoState();
}

class _TodoState extends State<Todo> {
  int i = 1;
  List<Column> todoos = [
    Column(),
  ];

  List<TextEditingController> listTexttCtrl = [TextEditingController()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("To do"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: i,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Slidable(
                  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextField(
                            controller: listTexttCtrl[index],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                            onChanged: (text) {
                              print(i);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconSlideAction(
                      color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[200],
                      icon: Icons.check_circle,
                    )
                  ],
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    IconSlideAction(
                        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[200],
                        icon: Icons.more_horiz)
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            i += 1;
            listTexttCtrl.add(TextEditingController());
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent[700],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```